# What is this hashtag in the Racket code?

Tags: racket

I have the following code:

```
(plot (function sin (- pi) pi #:label "y = sin(x)"))
```

But while solving SICP I did not encounter such a construct: `#:label "y = sin(x)"`
What does the hash tag mean?

Answer (score 6):

It's an [optional keyword argument](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/Optional_Keyword_Arguments.html), an optional extra argument for the function [`function`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/renderer2d.html?q=plot#%28def._%28%28lib._plot%2Fmain..rkt%29._function%29%29) that is passed by name. `#:label` is the keyword, and `"y = sin(x)"` is the value. All keywords have the form of a hashtag and a colon followed by the keyword name, e.g. `#:label`, `#:foo`, `#:blah`, etc. See [Keywords](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/keywords.html?q=keyword#%28tech._keyword%29) in the docs.